# One/Two tailed confidence interval of a single random variable in case of unknown mean and known variance

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

Suppose we have a random variable $Y$ which follows normal distribution of unknown mean $\mu$ and variance is $9$. Suppose we have to calculate the one or two tailed confidence interval, will the formula be the same i.e. 
  $ P( -z_{\alpha/2} \le \frac{Y - \mu}{\sigma} \le z_{\alpha/2})$

Comment: Title says 'test', text says 'confidence interval'. Please clarify. For a one-sided procedure, you will need to cut $\alpha$ from one tail of the distribution, instead of $\alpha/2$ from both tails. // Are you sure you have only a single observation $Y,$ or do you have the sample mean $\bar Y$ of $n$ independent realizations $Y_i?$ If it's $\bar Y,$ then $Z = \frac{\bar Y - \mu}{3/\sqrt{n}} \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$

Comment: @BruceET I edited the question to confidence interval. Also it's a single random variable $Y$ and not the sample mean. What will happen in this case?

Comment: Two-sided 95% CI is $Y \pm 1.96(3).$ (1) Give general version for $100(1-\alpha)$% CI. (2) Decide whether you want an upper or lower bound for the one-sided CI, find z-value that cuts $\alpha$ from appropriate tail.